# List of custom proxy APIs is empty in the New Project Wizard in SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

In API Portal I have created API proxy for Northwind service and product with this API (OpenSAP), I have also created Application with this product in Developer Portal with the same name OpenSAP.

I have created destinations in my HCP account for API Management Catalog and for the API Proxy with following parameters:

For the API Proxy:

`Description=for OpenSAP APImgmt demo Type=HTTP TrustAll=true Authentication=BasicAuthentication WebIDEUsage=api_mgmt_proxy Name=APIMgmt_APIPortal WebIDEEnabled=true URL=https\://s**********trial-trial.apim1.hanatrial.ondemand.com\:443/ ProxyType=Internet User=**********`

[image: API proxy destination]

For API Management Catalog:

`Name=APImgmt URL=https\://devportalu34f5b50f-s***********trial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/ ProxyType=Internet Type=HTTP WebIDEEnabled=true Authentication=AppToAppSSO WebIDEUsage=api_mgmt_catalog Description=for apimgmt OpenSap demo dev portal`

[image: Api mgmt catalog destination]

But I'm still unable to see list of APIs in webide service catalog when creating new project from template.

[image: Empty list of APIs in webide]

What settings can I fix to see the list of APIs in WebIde?

In the network tab of WebIDE I can see the same list of my API applications as in Dev portal, so destinations are probably configured correctly.

[image: network req in webide]

This is the same application in Dev portal:

[image: Dev portal apps]

[image: Product in application]

API proxy with associated product in API Portal:

[image]

I'm logged in to WebIDE and API Management services from the same s-user account.

Best regards,
Anna

Comment: Have you [deployed](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hcp-apim-create-api/_jcr_content.github-proxy.1578987322.file/09-SaveAndDeploy.png) your APIs?

Comment: @Suncatcher yes, API has status deployed in API Portal

Comment: `Простите, о каких данных речь?` the ones I blurred on the first pictures, dashboard URL and email.

Comment: you should select API Management Catalog destination in Fiori create master, not the API Proxy destination

Comment: @Suncatcher  destination with the name APImgmt points to the API Management Catalog